# Permission to write in partition comes and goes

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab

Since I upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04 I have problems mounting my second drive (only read). I've tried a lot of things, probably just to mess up things.

This is my /etc/fstab line:

```
LABEL=warehouse /mnt/warehouse auto rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The fact is that since I changed the fstab, when I star my machine I can write in the drive, but afer a while, it changes to read only, and I can't write :(

I guess it's a problem of permissions, but I'm lost. I'm sure that if you wan't to help me you'll need more info, please ask whatever is relevant and I'll try to post it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I asume it's mounted read only then, you can check with `findmnt /mnt/warehouse` after start if it's mounted correctly and a second time when it changed to readonly to see if it still is mounted rw.

Comment: I may be wrong, but this sounds like impending drive failure if it’s switching automatically to read only. Whatever else you try, I’d make sure your backups of that data are sound.

Comment: This is the first time:
`/mnt/warehouse /dev/sda1 exfat  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0117,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,iocharset=utf8,errors=remoun`
And this after a while:
`/mnt/warehouse /dev/sda1 exfat  ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,fmask=011`
Also, I have detected that this happens when Thunderbird accesses folders in this partition... Looks like it breaks something?